# Unable to retrieve the correct enclosing instance of 'this'

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss

Unfortunately I can't post the full code and I was not able to reproduce it with a smaller sample, yet.
I hope this explanation will suffice.

If I try to retrieve the value from "var" at the breakpoint, I always get this message:

```
Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
Unable to retrieve the correct enclosing instance of 'this'
```

The first 2 levels of the variables view looks like this:

```
this    MENU$1  (id=291)    
   this$0   MENU  (id=292)  
   this$0   MENU  (id=292)
```

For whatever reasons, there are 2 this$0 entries with the same id.

I can watch the value of var in the variables view but I am not able to execute "var", "this.var" or anything involving var in the display or expressions view or directly in the code.

```
public class MENU{

  private String var;
  ...
  private void menup() {
     this.main("menup",
         new MainProcess() {
             public void run() {
                 System.out.println(var); // breakpoint here
                 ...
             }
         }
     );
  }
  ...
}
```

The call flow of MainProcess.run() is a little weird and all I can provide is this stacktrace:

```
 MENU$1.run() line: 173 
 MENU(Application).mainRun(Application$Main) line: 2688 
 MENU(Application).main() line: 2529    
 MENU(MainApplication).runApplication() line: 54    
 ApplicationHandler.dxfr(MainApplication, Record) line: 256 
 ApplicationSession$ApplicationRunner.run() line: 138   
 Thread.run() line: 662 [local variables unavailable]
```

EDIT:

results of executions in display view:

```
this            This actually seems to successfully return this.toString()
this.var        cannot be resolved or is not a field
var             Unable to retrieve the correct enclosing instance of 'this'
MENU.this.var   Unable to retrieve the correct enclosing instance of 'this'
```

The code is running in a JBoss 4 application server.

Comment: Have you tried `MENU.this.var`?

Comment: Yes, that does not work either. It gives the same error as "var".

Answer (score 1):

By this statement:

```
    ...
    this.main("menup",
        new MainProcess() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(var); // breakpoint here
                ...
```

you create an anonymous class which extends / implements MainProcess (depending on whether this is a class or interface). Anonymous classes should, in general, be able to access parent class's fields with `MENU.this.var`, as suggested by others. Since this doesn't seem to work, you can try:

```
  MENU$1.this.var
```

If this works, this means that you have another `var` field within the anonymous class (most likely inherited from `MainProcess`).

Overall I would highly recommend you use explicitly defined inner classes instead of anonymous classes - this makes things much more clear and helps avoid confusion:

```
public class MENU{

  private String var;
  ...
  private void menup() {
     this.main("menup", new MyMainProcess() );
  }
  ...
  private class MyMainProcess extends MainProcess {
     public void run() {
         System.out.println(var); // breakpoint here
         ...
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: MENU$1.this.var results in "MENUA$1 cannot be resolved to a type"
MainProcess does not have any variables. It's an abstract class that implements Runnable(). MainProcess.run() is invoked directly from Application.mainRun() as it's not supposed to run in another thread.
I've tried to run the code above with stripped down versions of all involved classes but as of yet I was not able to reproduce the problem. The stripped down versions work as expected, which is the reason I have not attached them to the question.

Comment: What if you use inner classes (I updated my answer above with a sample)? Does this help?

Comment: Yes, that does work. I guess noone who works with the code will like that workaround but it's better than not beeing able to debug at all. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Again, I would recommend that you avoid anonymous classes whenever possible. They are faster to write, but lead to confusion and make the code harder to read.